# Can multiple Freeform recipients be set per drop-down option?

Tags: solspace-freeform

For example, can I set the following to set one chosen recipient to be sent to multiple emails?

{exp:freeform:form
    form_name="request_a_quote"
    recipients="yes" 
    recipient1="email.A@site.com|email.B@site.com" 
    recipient2="email.C@site.com" 
    recipient3="email.D@site.com,email.D@site.com" 
    required="name|email|phone_number"}

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to send to multiple addresses when using the recipients="yes" parameter. I would recommend setting up an address that recieves the message and then automatically forwards it to all the desired recipients.

To clarify 
recipients1="fakefoward@domain.com"
reciipients2="fakeforward2@domain.com"

Then in fakeforward@domain.com email settings have it forward to all the emails you need. Same with fakeforward2@domain.com

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible out of the box. We've solved this previously by writing a Freeform hook to handle the multiple notifications. See: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/extension_hooks/

Answer (score 1):

I remember looking into this a while back but ultimately did not need to implement it. I think it's not possible to do with Freeform on its own but you could accomplish it with Postmaster.

It may also be possible to do something with MX Notify Control but I would certainly look at Postmaster first as it's extremely powerful.

**Reading your question again I realised I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Do you want the same email sent to multiple addresses or multiple emails sent to the same address?**

Comment: I want three or four options in a drop down and depending on what is chosen the query/form being directed to one or more email addresses specified for that option. Make sense?

Comment: Yep. Do you want the email addresses concealed? I assume so or you could just add them as comma separated  values to the options of your select. I think you may need Postmaster to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working exampled.

```
{exp:freeform:form
                form_name="contact"
                form:class="mwi-form"
                recipients="yes"
                recipient_user_input="yes"  
                recipient_user_template="notify_contact" 
                return="contact/thank-you"
            }
                <fieldset>
                    <label class="col1">
                        First & Last Name
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="">
                    </label>
                    <label class="col1">
                        Phone Number
                        <input type="text" name="phone" value="">
                    </label>
                    <label class="col1">
                        Your Email Address
                        <input type="text" class="require" name="email" value="">
                    </label>
                    <label class="col1">
                        Battery Outfitters Location
                        <select name="recipient_email_user">
                            <option value="PShumaker@batteryoutfitters.com">Select Location</option>
                        {exp:channel:entries channel="location" dynamic="no"}   
                            <option value="{location_email}">{title}</option>
                        {/exp:channel:entries}                  
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label class="col1">
                        Message
                        <textarea name="user_message"></textarea>
                    </label>
                    <button class="btn blue" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>

                    <input type="hidden" name="spamfreeform_name" value="first_name" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="spamfreeform_email" value="email" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="spamfreeform_fields" value="user_message" />
                </fieldset>
            {/exp:freeform:form}
```

Make sure the value of the options in the recipient_email_user select are pipe separated email@domain.com|email@domain.com|etc...